# jQuery .hover mouse enter not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following function I have written which is partially working. The mouse enter on hover animation is not working however the mouse leave animation is. As far as I can tell from the documentation it is written correctly but I can't see what's wrong. Any ideas? :)

```
function hoveranim (){

        $(this).hover(function() {

             $(this).animate({left: '+=260px'}, '6000');

        },

        function() {

            $(this).animate({left: '-=260px'}, '6000');

             }
         )};

        $('div#feedback-form-container').on('hover', hoveranim);
```

Comment: You are calling your hover function on the hover event. That means that once the hoveranim() function is coming into effect, the hover event has already passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your function on the `hover` event. That means that once the `hoveranim()` function is coming into effect, the `hover` event has already passed, meaning it will not work, while mouseout *will*.

I suggest you rewrite it to a function that extends jQuery (which also allows for chaining, might come in handy)

```
jQuery.fn.hoveranim = function () {
    $(this).hover(function() {
         $(this).animate({left: '+=260px'}, '6000');

    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '-=260px'}, '6000');
         }
     )};
```

Then bind to it like this, in the document ready event ('`$(document).ready`)

```
$('div#feedback-form-container').hoveranim();
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ledpq/) for a demo.

PS: note that when you animate the element to **move**, you automatically trigger the mouseout event as you are moving the element away from beneath the cursor. See my fiddle for that (potentially unwanted) effect.

To circumvent that, I would suggest introducing a second element, which will remain static, preferably is invisible (though it should still be a block element) and is positioned **above** the element to be moved. Then rewriting the function to accept an optional `elem` parameter, specifying the element which is to be moved when this element is hovered.

I have worked this out in [another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUuWj/) ([and here it is with an invisible hover_check](http://jsfiddle.net/wz8Cz/))

Comment: Thanks for the info c_kick! I see what you mean about the mouseout event being triggered. What's the best way to stop that?

Comment: Stopping it is as simple as not including the mouseout function. But then you'll have to think about when the element moves back. What I would do is introduce a second element, positioned exactly beneath the element to be animated, which is invisible and stays where it is. Then binding the hoveranim() function to that element, and rewriting the function to point at the element to be moved (instead of $(this)).

Comment: Excuse me, the second element needs to be on top for hovering to work. Anyway, I just created that variant for you, see my edit and second fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write great explanations @c_kick it helped a lot!